# Laravel 5.2 - Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found, on live server only

Tags: php, laravel-5, guzzle

I have my config/mail 'driver' set to mandrill, host, port, etc. including in services.php mandrill secret set.

Sending Mail works fine locally, but on the live server I get:

> Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

I have tried "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0", and then back to "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0", no luck. I have done composer update, and dump-autoload still no luck on my live server. Been through every other associated Stackoverflow question and still can't resolve.

Comment: Made the error stand out.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these simple steps:

**First:** Place this on top of your class

```
use Guzzlehttp\Client;
```

**Second:** Inside your function,  instead of using

```
$client = new Client();
```

use

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

**reference:**

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

try composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle without specifying the version. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**Error ?**  the library GuzzleHttp (which is a Simple interface for building query strings, POST requests, streaming large uploads, streaming large downloads, using HTTP cookies, uploading JSON data ) is either missing or mis-configured.

**Solution :**  run the following command on your terminal(root folder):

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^6.5
```